# How to Display particular text from .txt file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to get only the IP address from a particular text file.

The text file contains:

> ```
> Pinging www.google.com [216.58.196.164] with 32 bytes of data:
> Reply from 216.58.196.164: bytes=32 time=81ms TTL=53
> Reply from 216.58.196.164: bytes=32 time=80ms TTL=53
> Reply from 216.58.196.164: bytes=32 time=82ms TTL=53
> Reply from 216.58.196.164: bytes=32 time=84ms TTL=53
>
> Ping statistics for 216.58.196.164:
>     Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
> Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
>     Minimum = 80ms, Maximum = 84ms, Average = 81ms
> ```

I need an output file only that IP address at first line `[216.58.196.164]` after `www.google.com`.
I need to get the IP address of any website URL as output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Separate IP from text in ping output?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21914334/separate-ip-from-text-in-ping-output)

Comment: Please read the entire [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page and learn how to ask here! Have you even bothered to search? simply typing [ping output](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+ping+output) into the search box delivers tons of results tagged [tag:batch-file]...

Answer (score 1):

in two lines in a .bat file:

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=3" %%a in ('findstr Pinging foo.txt') do echo %%a
```

`findstr` prints the line where the www.google.com pattern occurs, after that `for` splits the line according to space chars, and we only consider the third token.

if you want to strip the brackets:

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /F "tokens=3" %%a in ('findstr Pinging foo.txt') do (
set V=%%a
set V=!V:[=!
set V=!V:]=!
)
echo !V!
```

Comment: its working. but, it includes also "[ ]" < this symbol. i don't want that , i need only ip address as output bro. pls help

Comment: Awesome bro its working. And one more problem its working only for www.google.com .. but i need it for any url what i written to ping ip ...mean in that www.google.com the url must be any. so how to do that bro output only ip for any url which typed. please help me bro. once again thank u

Comment: Just replace `www.google.com` by `Pinging` which matches the same line anyway. Now it's generic. Check [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims=[" %%f in (input.txt) do (for /f "delims=]" %%g in ("%%f") do echo %%g)
```

Comment: @vijayarokiaraj You're welcome. Please mark my answer as a solution.

Answer (score -2):

## Some Explanations

I do expect to give a definitive answer through bash. The basic pattern I used is to match an IP number which is in range [0-255] an consist of `[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5])"`: because there never write `027` in IP but `27`. Maybe it's just a good practice.

Now, this `PATTERN` is immediately followed by a period (`.`); both repeat themselves three times `(PATTERN\.){3}` and then comes the last part which also matches `PATTERN`.

It comes out to become `(PATTERN\.){3}PATTERN`... ie

```
(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]))\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]))
```

## The Answer

- If your file is `~/ping-output.txt`
- I used `grep` to filter 'em out
- the `-o` parameter is to output only the matching part
- I used question mark (`?`) just as an habit: to be sure that copy & pasting won't capture unnecessary numbers

> `cat` *"~/ping-output.txt"* | `grep` -oE *"(?(?[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2(?[0-4][0-9]|5[0-5])).){3}(?[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2(?[0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]))"*